# Retrieve The line number of The TSV file being read by flatfileitemReader in spring batch process

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, csv, spring-batch

My Requirement: I have a TSV FILE with millions of records in it. I use flatfileitemreader to read these values in chunks which goes to precessor to apply business logic to data and then use jdbcBatchItemWriter to write the value obtained. I want to add the insert  the line number of TSV row being read along with the row in database so that later in my business logic if i find any error in the value inserted , then i can move it to some error file along with its row number. so that the client knows which line number the error occurred in.

Problem Statement: I have to store the line number of the TSV file record in database along with its content.

eg:- SAMPLE TSV FILE

```
Name Age Tier
Ram  24   3
Sam  12   1
Rose 18   2
Dan  43   3
Mini 10   1
Lily 19   2
```

How I want it to be stored

```
text            line number
Lily|19|2         6
Dan|43|3          4
Ram|24|3          1
Sam|12|1          2
Mini|10|1         5
Rose|18|2         3
```

How it is being stored

```
text            line number
Lily|19|2         1
Dan|43|3          1
Ram|24|3          6
Sam|12|1          4
Mini|10|1         5
Rose|18|2         5
```

in my step i have a task executor configured in the step like this:-

```
@Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory().get("step1").<InputFormatClass, OutputFormatClass>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunksize))
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writerJdbc())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
```

I suspect that due to task executor(multi threading) , my line number is getting read parallely and thus not getting correctly assigned.

Note:- I am using a custom reader with same implementation as flatfileItemReader, i have appended the lineNumber to the line being read in `protected T doRead() throws Exception`

Please suggest a way in which I can insert the row number correctly in multithreaded enviornment.